# Pyramid authentication testing with webtest

Tags: python, authentication, pyramid, webtest

I configured my **pyramid** app in order to have an `user` object attached to `request` once it has been authenticated following the [official tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-cookbook/en/latest/auth/user_object.html). So far so good... but while it works perfectly and I can test it using a browser, I don't understand why in webtest tests `user` is not attached to the request.
I configured my test class in this way:

```
from my_pyramid_app import main as make_app
from webtest.app import TestApp
from pyramid import testing

class LoginTestCase(TestCase):   
    def setUp(self):
        self.config = testing.setUp()
        self.app = TestApp(make_app({}))
```

And in a test:

```
# submit valid login data to /login and expect redirect to "next"
response = self.app.post('/login', data, status=302)
redirect = response.follow()
```

It works as expected, user gets authenticated and redirected to the path specified in "next", but `redirect.request` does not contain `user`. Why? What should I do?

ps. the [documentation of webtest](http://webtest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testapp.html#modifying-the-environment-simulating-authentication) says:

> The best way to simulate authentication is if your application looks
>   in environ['REMOTE_USER'] to see if someone is authenticated. Then you
>   can simply set that value, like:
>
> app.get('/secret', extra_environ=dict(REMOTE_USER='bob'))

but honestly it sounds demential to me :/ (I mean if I define a variable manually what is the sense of the test?!)

Comment: I don't have an answer to your issue, but the Pyramid Community Cookbook is not "official documentation". It is a community-contributed collection of recipes. Official documentation may be found at http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/

Comment: What kind of mechanism it should have to maintain the user over separate requests? In normal web server you usually do this with sessions, cookies, etc.

Answer (score -1):

both webtest and pyramid use webob but this doesn't mean that pyramid's request is the same object than webtest's response.request

the only immutable object shared between webtest and the tested application is the environ dictionary.

This mean that you may be able to retrieve your user if you store it in request.environ with a key like 'myapp.user' (dot and lowercase are important, see PEP333).